# Display data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Created next structure in my database, and now want to display data in my list

[image]

Tried to add next code in `onViewCreated`:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val wordsRef = databaseReference?.child("talk-6e3c0")?.child("words")

        val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                topWordsList.clear()
                for (wordsSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val topWord = wordsSnapshot.getValue(TopWord::class.java)
                    topWord?.let { topWordsList.add(it) }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("some", "Error trying to get targets for ${databaseError.message}")
            }
        }
        wordsRef?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

Method `onDataChanged` was called, but i can't get name for example.

My model:

```
data class TopWord(
    val name: String = "",
    val description: String = ""
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't getting something because you are adding the name of your project as a child in the reference and there is no need for that. So please change the following line of code:

```
val wordsRef = databaseReference?.child("talk-6e3c0")?.child("words")
```

to

```
val wordsRef = databaseReference?.child("words")
```

I just removed the call to `.child("talk-6e3c0")?`.

Comment: thanks, i can accept answer after 8 minutes.
But one more little question, can i rename my dataBase?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. There is no way you can change your `talk-6e3c0` project id.